# How to total Count in mongoDB?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Could you please tell me how to count total `person` which have status `p`.
Here is my code
https://mongoplayground.net/p/d2Bmk4srq0O

```
db.collection.aggregate({
  $group: {
    _id: "$Department",
    totalAttendance: {
      $sum: "$Status"
    },

  }
})
```

**I want to count all document which has status `p`**

**expected output . something like that**

```
[
  {
    "_id": "THBS",
    "totalAttendance": 10
  },
  {
    "_id": "HUAWEI",
    "totalAttendance": 2
  }
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need put [**`$sum`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/) [**`$cond`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/)itionally here

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$Department",
    "totalAttendance": {
      "$sum": {
        "$cond": [
          { "$eq": [{ "$ltrim": { "input": "$Status" } }, "P       "] },
          1,
          0
        ]
      }
    }
  }}
])
```

[**MongoPlayground**](https://mongoplayground.net/p/D8baB3T2sq2)